# multithreading scope

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

So I've spent all weekend reading up on and researching Multithreading in .net and there's one question that I can't quite understand.

say I have a button and when I click this button I want to upload a file to Amazon S3, now obviously this upload task will take a few seconds and I don't want to stop everything else while it does so. So this is where the thread comes in.

So then a problem comes in, if the user clicks the button again I don't want to start another thread to upload the file unless the first thread has completely finished, to try to avoid redundancy.

everywhere I read regarding multithreading described declaring the thread when I required it, but if I do that on a button click surely I will be creating some kind of conflict with the name of the thread as the second time the button is clicked there will already be a thread with the same name.

So my solution was to declare the thread at the beginning of the class. Create a sub with the code to upload the file. and then when the button was clicked check to see if the thread is alive before running it.
but then I found out I can't just make a thread start over once it has finished.

So What I can't quite understand is how I manage to make a task that is required to execute multiple times run in a separate thread. Am I expected to create a new thread everytime I want it to run? Does that mean I will need to create a new thread with a unique name? what happens to a thread once it has completed? I have read that aborting a thread is very bad, but am I expected to just leave it there forever not doing nothing and unable to remove it? does this mean that if the application runs for a long period of time that I could en up with thousands of "dead" threads hanging around doing nothing?

Here is a markup version of what i'm doing in case that makes things easier for people.

```
Public Class Form1
    Shared UploadThread As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf UploadLoop)

    Shared Sub UploadLoop()
        'code to upload a file to amazon S3
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If (UploadThread.IsAlive) Then
            MsgBox("upload not completed")
        Else
            UploadThread.Start()
        End If
    End Sub 
End Class
```

Comment: Simply set the button's Enabled property to *False*.  Enable it again when the transfer completes, you'll prefer the RunWorkerCompleted event that BackgroundWorker provides.  Easy peasy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A completed thread is in a "dead" state. You cannot easily do much with it and you should rather instantiate a new thread each time:

```
Shared UploadThread As Thread

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If UploadThread IsNot Nothing AndAlso UploadThread.IsAlive Then
        MsgBox("upload not completed")
    Else
        UploadThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf UploadLoop))
        UploadThread.Start()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks bob, so I can keep using the same name for the thread I just have to declare it again?

Comment: Also what happens if this gets done 1000 times will there just be 999 dead threads hanging around in memory or will they be cleaned each time the thread is redefined?

Comment: @SimonGreen : The "name" is the name of the variable pointing to your thread. The actual thread doesn't have a name and will go out of scope if you set the variable to a new thread instance - which brings us to your second question: When a managed object goes out of scope it will be detected by the Garbage Collector (when it runs) as having no more references to it. The Garbage Collector will then collect the object, thus freeing all the memory it has reserved. So **no**: You **won't** have 999 dead threads lying around, only one active thread.

Comment: @SimonGreen : See the [**documentation about Garbage Collection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks guys very much. It was this bit I couldn’t get my head around.